# Laravel migration doesn't add table in DB

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I added a new table in migration in file `2018_02_08_094356_create_currency_table.php`..

And this is the code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCurrencyTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('currency', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->decimal('usdeur', 15, 2);
            $table->decimal('usdchf', 15, 2);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('currency');
    }
}
```

When I run `php artisan migrate`, there is only default laravel users (and migration) table in my DB. No currency one.

What could be the reason?

**EDIT**

Everything was fine with migrations. The problem was this:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length
>   is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table users add unique
>   users_email_unique(email))
>
> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071
>   Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Solution is to add this in `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Source: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

Comment: If you don't have data you need to keep, run `php artisan migrate:fresh` first. Sounds like you have migration records in the db. This will drop all your tables so be warned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `composer du` to register the migration class first.

Then run `php artisan migrate` command to execute a new migration.

Comment: composer du means composer dump-autoload ?

Comment: @SuYang it's a shortcut for `composer dump-autoload`. You can use both.

Comment: It's still not working. Really confused right now! :/.. I get this: `SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists`

Comment: @harunB10 did you get any errors after doing this? Also, make sure you don't have `currency` table before executing the migration.

Answer (score 1):

open AppServiceProvider.php
write the below code:

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

The table name must be plural
rollback your migration using

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

or

manually delete the table from your database and migration table
and try the below code:

```
migration command:
php artisan make:migration create_currencies_table
```

Code:

```
class CreateCurrenciesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('currencies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->decimal('usdeur', 15, 2);
            $table->decimal('usdchf', 15, 2);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('currencies');
    }
}
```

now run

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Still not working. Don't know what I am missing here... I did `composer du` also...

Answer (score 0):

All the migrations record are recorded in table migrations.It is indicate that you created it before.So delete the records about currencies in table  migrations and run `php artisan migrate` again. what's more,refresh your database and check if the table currencies has created.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.4 uses utf8mb4 by default. One way to fix this error, is to default back to utf8.

Go to your config\database.php and change the database charset to uft8 and the collation to utf8_unicode_ci:

```
'mysql' => [
    //..
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    //..
],
```